# Constructor Java Programming

Tags: java, constructor

The Survey class will have a static class variable that stores the current respondent’s ID. As respondents complete the survey, this value will be incremented by one.
The Survey class will have an instance variable to hold the title of the survey.
The Survey class should have two overloaded constructors.
The first constructor should take no arguments. It should set the survey title to a default value of “Customer Survey”.
The second constructor should accept a String value for the survey title. It should reset the static respondent ID to zero. It should set the survey title to the value passed into the constructor.
The survey class should have a generateRespondentId() method which returns the next value of the respondent ID. This method should increment the static instance variable for the respondent ID by one.

```
public class Survey {
    String surveyTitle = "";

    static int respondentID = 0;

    static int generateRespondentID(){
        return ++respondentID;    
    }

    public Survey(){
        surveyTitle = "Customer Survey";
    }

    public Survey(String newSurveyTitle){
        respondentID=0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Survey s = new Survey();
        System.out.println(s.getSurveyTitle());
        System.out.println(s.generateRespondentID());
        System.out.println();

        Survey s2 = new Survey("My Survey");
        System.out.println(s2.getSurveyTitle());
        System.out.println(s2.generateRespondentID());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(s2.generateRespondentID());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. I am struggling with the second constructor it should set the survey title as the value passed to the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more information in order to help you. What is your question? What part are you struggling with?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: It does say at the very bottom.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "I am struggling with the second constructor" is a statement, not a question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Oh, not forming it as a question is *nothing* on the scale of first time question issues out there.  It's the vagueness of it that bothers me.

Comment: Amanda, in the second constructor you appear to have at least half of the requirement. What's causing you trouble with the other half?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not phrasing as a question is often a symptom of vagueness...and the easiest to point out to get my point across.

Comment: _"The second constructor should accept a String value for the survey title."_ Something is still missing from the second constructor. You have the new title as a parameter, but you never update the instance field with it.

Comment: Also, just so you know, a class should *never* be designed as per those requirements in the real world. (A constructor having a side-effect on a static field based on which constructor you call? No no no no...) But I assume the requirements were given to you.

Comment: I am not sure how to finish the second constructor. It should set the survey title to the value passed into the constructor. this part is what I am struggling on

Comment: That's just a setting a variable. In fact, you already did that in the first constructor but you assigned it to a hard-coded string instead of the parameter passed to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement the following code below should work.

```
public Survey(String newSurveyTitle){
    respondentID=0;
    SurveyTitle = newSurveyTitle;
 }
```

You were missing the code for setting the title of the survey in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve, after reading your code, I was able to understand that you are trying to learn how to use Constructors with getter and setter, the issue you were having was that you failed to declare the property surveyTitle

```
`
public class Survey {
private String surveyTitle;

public String getSurveyTitle() {
    return surveyTitle;
}
static int respondentID = 0;
static int generateRespondentID(){
    return ++respondentID;    
}
public Survey(String surveyTitle) {
    this.surveyTitle = surveyTitle;
}

public Survey() {
    surveyTitle = "Customer Survey";
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Survey s = new Survey();
   System.out.println(s.getSurveyTitle());
   System.out.println(Survey.generateRespondentID());
   System.out.println();

   Survey s2 = new Survey("My Survey");
   System.out.println(s2.getSurveyTitle());
   System.out.println(s2.generateRespondentID());
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println(s2.generateRespondentID());
   System.out.println();
 }
}
```

`

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. I just had to add the get survey title!

Comment: You welcome, You can accept it as answer or up vote the solution, if it solved the problem at hand

Answer (score 0):

First class variables defined level private

```
private String surveyTitle;
private static int respondentID
```

and accessing them through its getters and setters

the second constructor will receive the title of the survey should only assign its previously declared private variable and get your getter

```
public Survey(String newSurveyTitle){
this.surveyTitle = newSurveyTitle;
this.respondentID=0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- you should chain your constructors
- you shouldn't use statics for id generation, but if you do, make them thread safe

Snippet:

```
public class Survey {
  static AtomicInteger respondentID = new AtomicInteger(0);
  final private String surveyTitle;

  public Survey(String surveyTitle) {
    this.surveyTitle = surveyTitle;
  }

  public Survey() {
    this("Customer Survey");
  }

  static int generateRespondentID() {
    return respondentID.incrementAndGet();
  }

  public String getSurveyTitle() {
    return surveyTitle;
  }

  //Other methods...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> The second constructor should accept a String value for the survey title.

You need to set the survey title field to the `String` value which was given as a parameter to the constructor. If you don't know how to do this, I suggest that you do some research on the assignment operator in Java.